# Android Maps Coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am getting json response from an Api. The response looks like this.

```
{
 "CarsList": [{
 "coordinate": {
 "latitude": 53.46036882190762,
 "longitude": 9.909716434648558
 },
 "heading": 344.19529122029735
 },
 {
 "coordinate": {
 "latitude": 53.668806556867445,
 "longitude": 10.019908942943804
 },
 "heading": 245.2005654202569
 },
 {
 "coordinate": {
 "latitude": 53.58500747958201,
 "longitude": 9.807045083858156
 },
 "heading": 71.63840043828377
 }
 ]
}
```

I need to create custom list items using the json Response data.
I am using latitude and longitude to get the location. I am confused as to what the "heading" parameter represents. Please help me in figuring out the purpose of this "heading" parameter. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a definition of heading in the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Navigation):

> When navigating on a sphere, a heading is the angle of a direction from a fixed reference point, usually true north. Within the Google Maps API, a heading is defined in degrees from true north, where headings are measured clockwise from true north (0 degrees).

Also you can see how it is calculated visually:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings